# Rails: parameter missing in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Here's the error message:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

Full error log

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:36:in `update_user_params'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:15:in `update'
```

the error highlights this line:

```
def update_user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:role)
    end
```

the parameters on the error are these:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"NVSo53F3PFIhOxDthMFCAxgTIDAewnxppsGTNzkp/Zc=",
 "admin"=>{"role"=>"user"},
 "commit"=>"Make User",
 "id"=>"2"}
```

Here's the form I'm using: show.html.erb

```
<tr id="dashfield">
    <td><%= @user.first_name%></td>
    <td><%= @user.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= @role %></td>
    <td><% if @role == 'admin'%>
          <%= form_for @role, method: :put do |f|%>
          <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => 'user'%>
          <%= f.submit 'Make User'%><%end%>
          <%else%>
          <%= form_for @role, method: :put do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => 'admin'%>
          <%= f.submit 'Make Admin'%>
          <%end%>
          <%end%></td>
</tr>
```

here's the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def index
    @allusers = User.all
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @role = @user.role
  end
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(update_user_params)
    redirect_to '/users'
    else
      redirect_to "/users/#{id}"
    end
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.role = 'user'
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to '/hours/new'
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end
  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
  end
    def update_user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:role)
    end
end
```

Is the error saying that it cannot find the databse, user? Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: I think you should use params["admin"]["role"] in here @user.update(params["admin"]["role"]) and check if it work

Comment: show the full error log please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is saying:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

because your `update_user_params` requires `user` to be present in the params. As it is not present in your params currently, so it's throwing this error.

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) to know how `params.require` works.

In your form, you can try adding something like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user, { :value => @user } %>
```

---

Comment: So user is the database I'd like to enter the information into, how can i include it in the params? or should i just try removing the params?

Comment: try my updated answer. see if that works. let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I found:

```
<td><% if @role == 'admin'%>
          <%= form_for @user, method: :put do |f|%>
          <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => 'user'%>
          <%= f.submit 'Make User'%><%end%>
          <%else%>
          <%= form_for @user, method: :put do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => 'admin'%>
          <%= f.submit 'Make Admin'%>
          <%end%>
          <%end%></td>
```

I just replaced the "@role" with "@user" and it works like a charm. this was a silly mistake, thank you for all who looked at it.

Comment: Btw, do you know that you can do the same with rails ujs (ex jquery.ujs) and button/link?  Smth like
`<%= link_to 'Make User', admin_path(role: :user), method: 'put'>`